Flickering videos when animating with SSR and react-spring
I'm trying to animate a <video> element in a reactjs/nextjs/ssr/react-spring project. Images and other elements works fine, also works when not using ssr. How can I get it to look good and not flicker?
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-spring-ssr-video-bug-y3kq5m
